# How can I register a rendering plugin for Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am having a hard time making a rendering plugin for Mojolicious work.
My plugin looks like this (for now):

```
package Mojolicious::Plugin::Renderer::XML;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin';

sub register {
    my ($self, $app, $conf) = @_;
    $app->renderer->add_handler('xml' => sub {
                    ${$_[2]} = 'say something';
                    return 1;
                } );
}
1;
```

and in the application I have:

```
plugin 'Renderer::XML';
```

and later

```
get '/x/xml' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render( xml => 'bar' );
};
```

I can see that the plugin gets registered (dumping the list of `renderer->handlers`, but it looks like the sub never even gets called (I inserted debugging output to check). I tried doing the same from inside the app as described [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Adding-a-handler-to-generate-binary-data), but no results.

Does anyone have a better clue than me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `render` sub implementation in [Mojolicious::Renderer](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-6.36/lib/Mojolicious/Renderer.pm#L85). You will see that the accepted data types are fixed. There is no way to add more with just a plugin.

Now look at [Mojolicious::Plugin::XML::Loy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::XML::Loy). He had to create a `render_xml` helper. Good enough!